# assignment from incompatible pointer type in linked list?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new bee to C. I am currently writing linked list in C. When compiling, it keeps complaining about "assignment from incompatible pointer type". My code is like this:

```
# include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct snode{
  struct snode *next;
  int val;
};

struct slist{
  struct snode *head;
  struct snode *tail;
  int len;
};

struct slist *mylist;

void slist_insert(int v){
  struct snode *newnode;
  newnode = (struct snode*)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
  newnode -> val = v;
  newnode -> next = NULL;


  if(mylist->head  = NULL){
    mylist->head  = malloc (sizeof(struct snode));
    mylist->tail = (struct snode*)malloc (sizeof(struct snode));
    mylist->head = newnode;
    mylist->tail = newnode;
    
  };

  else{
    mylist -> tail -> next = (struct snode*)malloc (sizeof(struct snode));
    mylist -> tail -> next = newnode;
  };
   mylist -> len +=1;  
};


main(){
    slist_insert(1);
    slist_insert(2);
    slist_insert(3);
    slist_insert(4);
    slist_insert(5);

    struct snode *temp;
    temp = (struct snode*)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
    temp = mylist-> head;
    while(temp -> next != NULL){
      printf("%d\n", temp -> val);
      temp  = temp -> next;
    };
  };
```

Here is the modified one. I am using linux terminal to run this program. The compiler I am using is gcc -std=gnu99

## UPDATE

```
slist.c: In function â:
slist.c:32: error: â without a previous â
slist.c: At top level:
slist.c:40: warning: return type defaults to â
```

Comment: Start by initializing your `mylist` pointer to NULL on its declaration line, or you're already jumping into the pool of **undefined behavior**. Honestly if it is a global it shouldn't even *be* a pointer in the first place. the node-chain yes, `mylist` no.

Comment: You're missing `#include <stdlib.h>` for a definition of `malloc`.  After that, you should remove the various casts you added to the returns from `malloc` - they're not required and are often casting to the wrong type, causing some of your errors.  This will leave you with a more manageable set of warnings/errors to work through.  Oh, and for future notice, its much more helpful if you post the compiler errors as well as the problem code.

Comment: @simonc on that regard, the two *consecutive* lines following the `head == NULL` condition.. /facepalm

Comment: @WhozCraig yep, although is there not also a `head=NULL` assignment in conditional problem there?

Comment: You read error message. It is good beginning. Now you can go further and read full error message - with line number where error actually occurs. It makes debugging much simpler.

Comment: @WhozCraig All global variables (more generally, all variables with static storage duration) are automatically initialized to the type-appropriate zero if they don't have an explicit initializer.  In the case of pointers, "the type appropriate zero" is NULL.

Comment: @simonc *ouch*. you're totally right. Can't see the forest for the tree kinda thing, I guess. Didn't even notice.

Comment: @Zack Really? because last I checked the standard dictates *static* s are guaranteed to be in zero-filled memory. I don't remember reading anything about globals in general. Is there a cite for that?

Comment: If I'd felt like being unhelpful, I could have just complained about the `test.c.32:3:error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’` (due to overuse of semicolons, looks like).

Comment: @WhozCraig C99 6.7.8p10 "If an object _that has static storage duration_ is not initialized explicitly, then [it is initialized to a type-appropriate zero]."  6.2.4p3 defines _static storage duration_ as applying both to objects declared explicitly `static`, and all objects "with external or internal linkage", which encompasses everything you're thinking of as "global".  (The C standard doesn't ever use the term "global variable"; the closest match is "object with external linkage".)

Comment: @Zack *Thank you*!! Much appreciated. Adding that to my reference list. Thanks for taking the time to get the section for us.

Comment: @WhozCraig It's no trouble at all.  I used to hack on GCC and I still have most of C99 rattling around in my brain.  (I do have to look up the section numbers. Fortunately the PDF is searchable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many problems with this code.  I am **ONLY** listing the problems that cause the "assignment from incompatible pointer" warnings.  Compile with `gcc -W -Wall` and fix *all* the warnings. And after you've done that there will still be bugs.

1. You need `#include <stdlib.h>`, right after the existing `#include <stdio.h>`, to make the declaration of `malloc` visible.  (If you don't do this, the compiler is obliged to assume that `malloc` returns `int`, even though it knows perfectly well that that's wrong.  This is what the "`incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’`" warning is trying to tell you.)
2. You are incorrectly casting `struct snode` allocations to `struct slist *` and then assigning them to `struct snode *` fields, in several places. Do not cast the return value of `malloc` to anything; just assign it.  (Note that you may see people deliberately casting the return value of `malloc` in code that needs to be compilable as C++ as well as C.  *Do not do this* until you are experienced enough to understand when it is necessary.  If your compiler insists on treating everything as C++ even when it's meant to be C, get a better compiler.)
3. `struct snode`'s `next` field should be declared as `struct snode *`, not `int *`.

Comment: please check the update. Seems there is something wrong after I changed it. It is complaining you cant use snode before you declare it.

Comment: Thanks for providing error messages, but you have some kind of character encoding problem, which has destroyed critical information.  (If you're not on Windows, try typing `export LC_ALL=C` at the shell prompt (exactly as shown) and then re-running the compiler.  If you are on Windows, do the same thing but without the `export`, I think.) Also, the line numbers don't seem to match the code you provided.  This means I don't know what's wrong.  Please correct.

Comment: ... Actually, a stab in the dark: You have to write `struct snode *`, not just `snode *`.

Comment: I am using linux to run this program. Just in case I am using gcc -o to compile the program. I will update my code again.Thanks for the help!

Comment: ... Are you using `tcsh`? If so, switch to `bash` or `zsh` immediately.  (And in the meantime, try `setenv LC_ALL C`.)  I observe that you are still casting the return value of `malloc`; remove all of those casts completely.  Anyhow, your remaining error messages do not include anything about incompatible pointer types.  If you cannot figure out what is still wrong, please ask a new question.  If you want someone to go through this program line by line and point out *all* of the remaining bugs (which are many), please go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Thanks! I am using Bash. Ive figured it out. Sadly, segmentation faults appeard right after it :(

Comment: If you're using Bash, `export LC_ALL=C` (exactly as shown) should have been a valid command.  And your segfaults are due to the many bugs which the compiler is not able to warn you about, like I've been saying.

Comment: It complains there is no "export" command. Alright I won't bother you for these stupid mistakes. Just saying I do think am good at programing until I learned C. Used to programing in Java and Python.

Answer (score 2):

Your `next`is a pointer to int, while you want it to be a pointer to struct snode, I assume.
Moreover, I assume that your `mylist` is supposet to be an slist instead of a pointer to an slist. And as has been pointed out in the comments, that membres of that mylist are not necessarily initialized (implementaiton dependent. With your mode of using a *pointer* for mylist, you need to malloc (and init) that guy first ...

Comment: But can I have a new snode in snode? I mean its not even built yet

Comment: @NobWong You are declaring the type only. Ponters are an exception to the rule that the type must be completely "known" at the moment of usage. That's because pointers are always the same size, no matter what they point to, hence the layout of the snode structure can be computed fine.

Comment: Stress *data* pointers are the same size, which *can* be different than code pointer sizing, though not particularly applicable in this usage.

Comment: @WhozCraig (1/2) POSIX requires *all* pointers to be the same size, and the only non-POSIX-compliant system you're likely to encounter nowadays is Windows, whose _de facto_ ABIs also all have all pointers the same size.  Having said that, the C standard requires only that all object pointers be convertible to `void *` and back without loss of information, and (implicitly, requiring a regrettable amount of close-reading to discover) that all pointers-to-`struct`-or-`union` types are the same size.

Comment: @WhozCraig (2/2) Historically, the most common case of pointers not being all the same, that I know about, was `char *` and `void *` being *bigger* than everything else (for a word-addressed machine).  `</pedant>`

Comment: @Zack Agreed. Further, not knowing if you're old enough to have experienced the joy, mixed model programming on x86 back in the day had classic pointer-size differences. It was a real mess. 64K limited code model (16 bit pointer) and 1MB data pointers (20bit) as one example. Ugh, the memories.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm old enough to remember those machines, but I never did any serious C programming on them.

Comment: @Zack Consider yourself lucky. It was a fiasco (but was all we had at the time unless you were fortunate enough to have something non-Intel in your rig).

Comment: @WhozCraig Come to think, Borland C and its `FAR whatever *` were pre-C89, weren't they?

Comment: @Zack Yes, as was C6. The first one I used from Borland was Turbo C 2.0, which came out in '89 (ironically). It followed most of the ANSI draft at the time, as I recall. With tiny, small, medium, large, and huge memory models; like I said, a real mess.